# elasticsearch how to query with two different fields with data range

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am using using elasticsearch, i have following fields in doc.

sale_start

sale_end

sale_price

selling_price

I want to query data which should be like:

if "sale_start" date and "sale_end" date is between the current date

then it should match the price range condition with sale_price

if "sale_start" date and "sale_end" date is not between the current date

then it should match the price range condition with selling_price

I searched a lot, but could not find a way to write condition like this. I am also new to elasticsearch. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If I got your requirement correctly, it could be expressed like this:

- The outer `bool/should` contains the two main cases:

  1. the current date `now` is in the interval [`sale_start`, `sale_end`] AND the `sale_price` is between the price bounds. Note that I've arbitrarily chosen the interval [1, 1000], but you can change that freely.
  2. the current date `now` is either before `sale_start` or after `sale_end` AND `selling_price` is in the [1, 1000] price range.

Query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "range": {
                  "sale_start": {
                    "lt": "now"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "sale_end": {
                    "gt": "now"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "sale_price": {
                    "gt": 1,
                    "lt": 1000
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "range": {
                  "sale_start": {
                    "gt": "now"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "sale_end": {
                    "lt": "now"
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "must": [
              {
                "range": {
                  "selling_price": {
                    "gt": 1,
                    "lt": 1000
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```